# Second Wordpress installation on IIS server

Tags: wordpress, iis, web-config

I currently have a working wordpress installation in my server root, but now I'm adding another wordpress site to subfolder "new-site".

It's an IIS server, so the web.config file should have this in the root directory, according to wordpress:

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
            <rule name="wordpress" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                <match url="*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
            </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The problem I'm facing now: How to modify the root's web.config file (below) so that the WP installation in /new-site works fine. (It's working fine on my localhost and I've changed the URLs in wp-options. The homepage on new-site looks fine but if you click on any link it'll be an error page of the root site.) Thanks!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4294967295" />
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>

        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="Main Rule" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                </rule>
                <rule name="wordpress" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                    <match url="*" />
                        <conditions>
                            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                        </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>

        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <clear />
                <add value="index.php" />
                <add value="index.html" />
                <add value="Default.htm" />
                <add value="Default.asp" />
                <add value="index.htm" />
                <add value="aboutus.html" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>

        <handlers>
            <remove name="PHP53_via_FastCGI" />
            <remove name="AboMapperCustom-1045478" />
            <add name="PHP53_via_FastCGI" path="*.php" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.3\php-cgi.exe" resourceType="Either" requireAccess="Script" />
        </handlers>   
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved. In the web.config in the subfolder, add `<clear />` so it won't be affected by the root's rule(s).

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear />
                <rule name="wordpress" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
            <match url="*" />
              <conditions>
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
              </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
          </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Source: http://forums.iis.net/post/1883731.aspx

Comment: Can you please post your final webconfig for both the root application and the subdirectory. I keep getting a 500.19 error and have tried all sorts of combinations with no luck so far!

Comment: Thank you, It worked and saved a lot of time :)