# web.config load website from specific folder

Tags: wordpress, azure, azure-web-app-service

I want to host multiple `wordpress` sites under the same domain, but different paths in `azure web apps`.

So on the server I would have a `web.config` under `wwwroot` and the `wordpress`sites under their own directory.

```
wwwroot - web.confing
        | \ wp1
        | \ wp2
```

Currently my `web.config` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
        <rule name="wordpress" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
            <match url="*"/>
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true"/>
                    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true"/>
                </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php"/>
        </rule></rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

and it works as long as all my files are in the wwwroot.

How should I rewrite it so it serves from `wp1` when I enter `domain.com/wp1` and serves `wp2` when I go to `domain.com/wp2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend leaving the default web.config in each Wordpress folder and create virtual directories in the Azure Portal for wp1 and wp2 - similar to the image below, but instead of blog2, you will have the root and 2 virtual directories /wp1 and /wp2.  In the root, put whatever static html or redirects you require:

[image]

Comment: I tried it, but I get `The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.` when I go to `/blog2`

Comment: When I added the `<clear />` rule to the inner `web.config` everything started to work. So I think the combination of your answers got me there. Thanks.

Comment: I actually am trying to do the same thing just locally on IIS and am facing the same problem. I have the web.config in the root and in the subdirectory and have tried adding the clear tag, but I still get an error on the blog 500.19. Im 99% sure this is still a problem with the web.configs but am at a loss. How did you manage to get this all working?

Comment: Don't use a sub-folder.

Comment: Do you mean for the wordpress files? Please explain further. I have set it up as a virtual application but the path is a sub folder within the main root.

Comment: Don't put an application like Wordpress (with a web.config) in a subfolder of an application folder that has another web.config.  Clearing out configurations is already problematic.

Answer (score 1):

The post ["WordPress installation on Root Folder & Sub Folder on IIS Server, url conflict"](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-installation-on-root-folder-sub-folder-on-iis-server-url-conflict?replies=5) on Wordpress support site may help you.

Also the SO question ["Second Wordpress installation on IIS server"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14966871/second-wordpress-installation-on-iis-server) may be helpful.

They both show a configuration where one installation is on the root and one in subdirectory. But these should offer guidance on your setup.

You can find a good walkthrough also from here: http://www.erichstauffer.com/web-design/install-wordpress-root-folder-sub-folder-windows-iis-server-godaddy